# Get company company's currency_id in qweb report Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I need to use company currency id in qweb report. i tried below codes, but nothing worked. Getting an error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

```
<span t-esc="company.id"/>

<span t-esc="o.company.id"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If `o` is the name of your record, which the report is printed for, and if the guideline from odoo was followed (which means the company is saved under the field `company_id`), then it should be:

```xml
<!-- example for currency name -->
<span t-field="o.company_id.currency_id.name" />
<!-- example for currency symbol -->
<span t-field="o.company_id.currency_id.symbol" />
```

Comment: i didn't get any object `o` in my qweb template. That's the issue.. How can i get a default object of a model in qweb report template?

Comment: So it's not a qweb template for reports but for the client?

Comment: Its qweb report. i inherited `report_saleorder`, and saved in /report/report_template.xml in my custom module.

Comment: Worked for me ! Thanks a lot